# Date/Time Picker not showing on Android 4.1.2 app

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have used JQuery Mobile 1.3.1 to create a form that has a date and a time picker using the code below:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="date">Date</label>
    <input name="date" id="date" placeholder="" value="" type="date" />
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="time">Time</label>
    <input name="time" id="time" placeholder="" value="" type="time" />
</div>
```

The date and time pickers display as expected when I open the web page with chrome on my laptop or safari on my phone as is shown below.

[image]

[image: <code>![enter image description here][2]</code>]

I created an Android 4.1.2 application that is basically just a PhoneGap app that points towards a URL that contains the JQuery Mobile code. The problem is that when I launch the app the date and time pickers are not displayed on the android application when I touch the input box only the keyboard appears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If phonegap uses the device's default browser to load the html as an app, it might not work on android because it does not fully support the new html5 input types "date" and "time". The HTML5 test proves it [here](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/android40.html#row-form-date). You can see [here](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/ios60.html#row-form-date) that iDevices support the new HTML5 date and time inputs. So, if phonegap uses a built in browser or webview, it may not work fully with android 4.x and lower.

Comment: I've found that the firefox application for android supports the new HTML5 types I am using. I have set the firefox app to be the default browser choice on my mobile phone (clicking links etc launches firefox). The date and timepickers work as expected when I visit the mobile website manually through firefox. However when I launch the phonegap app it must not be using firefox (despite me choosing it as the default browser) because I still can't see the date and time pickers. I know this is maybe a different question, but is there a way to specify what browser app phonegap launches with?

Comment: My understanding is that phonegap uses the built in webview class. This class uses the built in browser for Android to render its content. You would have to somehow override what WebView phonegap uses and replace it with one that you create by extending the WebView class and implementing firefox's rendering engine. This would be very difficult and unfeasible. You would be better off creating your own date and time pickers from scratch or using a javascript library that comes with one. I think jQuery might include one...

Comment: I didn't realize Phonegap uses the default browser to render the view. Would using Titanium offer a better solution?