# HTML tag <input> with type="date" doesn't work in WebView in LG Optimus G Pro Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, html, webview

In a web page requiring input for date of birth, it is not responding to the click on the in the WebView, but working on the built-in browser in the same device LG Optimus G Pro (Android 4.1.2).

The HTML snippet is:

```
<div class="classname">
  <label for="id_foo" class="label">Date of Birth:</label>
  <input id="id_foo" maxlength="10" class="intext" type="date" name="dateofbirth" value="1985-07-04" />
</div>
```

Is there any other solution other than external date picker library or creating one from scratch as mentioned in this post:

> [Date/Time Picker not showing on Android 4.1.2 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428021/date-time-picker-not-showing-on-android-4-1-2-app)

Comment: Maybe, this one might help you . [Invoke Date Picker from Web App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946919/invoke-native-date-picker-from-web-app-on-ios-android)

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="date">
```

still lacks wide-spread support according to my sampling at other questions here at stackoverflow.

Personally, I have tried that HTML5 input type in android 4.4.4 webview and to my surprise it does not work. However, it does work in my android 4.4.4 Chrome browser outside a webview. Not sure why.

You might need to fall back to a Jquery datepicker widget or your own implementation if you want a cross-browser/full-webview solution. I have written a *very simplistic* js approach for asking the user a date. Take a look at [Invoke native date picker from web-app on iOS/Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946919/invoke-native-date-picker-from-web-app-on-ios-android/24835538#24835538)