# Html5 tag input = type not working in dell tablet

Tags: html, cordova

I am new to phonegap and developing android app in which user can set time. Using following html tag.

```
<input type="time" id="time" name="time">
```

I have tried testing this code in micromax mobile it's working fine, but in dell tablet it is 
showing as normal text box. Please help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, it's not supported for andorid < 4.4. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) and [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime)

Comment: @Vucko ..Thanks :) android version is 4.2.2 . SO is there any other solutions?

Comment: Hi Vucko my micromax mobile android version is 4.2.1 but still it's working in that :(

Comment: What browser are you using on your micromax mobile?

Comment: I am not using any browser. It opens as if an android native app.

Comment: number pad is working but time and datetime both are not working

Comment: Have you [seen this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16428097/1763929)?

Comment: I will go through now. Thanks..

Comment: @Vucko I checked that link... SO how can we acheive this one ? Any links so that I can manually add time picker?